# Increment background-position-x using jQuery animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to animate a DIVs background-position-x using jQuery animate?

Ideally, the background-position-x will increment 20% when clicked.

Here is my code so far:

```
$('.cycle').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'background-position-x': '+20%' }, 500, 'linear');
});
```

But it only works for the first click.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.cycle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'background-position-x': '+=20%' }, 500, 'linear');
});
```

Comment: @Astro I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: i have a issue regarding background-position , as it does not work as same as Internet Explorer ? wat should i do

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
   $(function() {
      $('.element').css("backgroundPosition","0px 0px").animate({"backgroundPosition":"-200px 10px"});
    });
```